# Failure to upload file to servlet with https enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I am having a weird issue in my application.

Application Details:
- Spring 4, Java 8, Tomcat 8

When I enable **https** (in web.xml), and try to upload a multi-part file, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:1005)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347)
```

However, when I turn off **https** and make the request via **http** everything works correctly. Any ideas?

I am just testing with a very simple upload form right now:

```
<form action="../upload/TestUpload"
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Please specify a file, or a set of files:<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

The spring class is very simple right now - just printing out the file names without doing anything. However, the code doesn't even reach this action because 
fileupload fails to parse the stream.

```
@RestController
public class Upload {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(Upload.class);
    @RequestMapping(value="/TestUpload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<FileResult> handleFileUpload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request){
        //List<File> tempFiles = new LinkedList<File>();
        List<FileResult> files = new LinkedList<FileResult>();
        Iterator<String> itr = request.getFileNames();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile(itr.next()); 
                LOG.info(multipartFile.getName());
            }
          return files;

    }
```

**web.xml https snippet**

```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: You enable https in **web.xml**?! But loading your form with https is okay with no warnings?

Comment: Yes, the entire web application works with https enabled. The only thing that doesn't work is file upload.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by installing the latest version of tomcat 8 and latest version of jdk 8. Not sure what the issue was before, but might have been some rare bug or configuration error causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error with the application details: Spring 4.3.1, Java 7, Tomcat 8.5.4.
I found out that the Tomcat connector org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol does not work over the internet for uploaded files bigger than 20KB, though it works fine in localhost.
I ended up using the Tomcat connector org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol, which works fine.
I assume it has to do with the blocking vs. non-blocking I/O connector's characteristic.